# How a tunnelled wave has the same energy even when the amplitude is lower

Tags: waves, quantum-tunneling

As I know that amount of energy carried by a wave is related to the amplitude of the wave than how in quantum tunnelling, tunnelled wave have the same energy even they have lower amplitude. I am newbie to quantum world and may be it is stupid question but any answers would be appreciated :)

Comment: A wavefunction and a physical wave are two very different things. Energy and amplitude are not correlated on a wavefunction.

Comment: The amplitude of the wavefunction relates to the probability of the tunneling event occurring.

Comment: I have edited the title to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you probably-someone and @Jon for simple explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amplitude of a quantum mechanical wave function is irrelevant. All wave functions multiplied with a complex number are equivalent. Usually wave functions are normalized so that $$\int \psi \psi^*d^3r=1$$ Thus in quantum mechanics wave function amplitudes have nothing to do with energies. The normalized one particle wave function amplitude determines the probability of finding the particle in a certain infinitesimal volume at $\vec r$ by $$ \psi(\vec r) \psi^*(\vec r)d^3r$$ The decrease of the wave amplitude in tunneling at constant energy describes the reduced probability of a transmitted particle.

Comment: This link is useful for tunneling http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html

Comment: @annav -Thank you for the link which illustrates the tunneling nicely!

Comment: @AlokPathak  you could accept the answer of freecharly, on this site. Check the ν  on the left , below the up and down .